# Web Scraping: previous values are returning

Tags: php, web-scraping, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to fetch the score of the cricket (it updates in real-time) and to fetch the score, I'm using an HTML dom parser. Everything works perfectly fine except for the repetition of previous values. Sometimes it fetch the previous score which has already been fetched. Something like this

10 Score, 15 Score, 10 score (repeat), 15 score (repeat)

I did a lot of research and tried lots of different ways to fix this problem but nothing worked out. In case, if you are thinking this is a cache problem, no it is not (I already verified it)

```
clearstatcache();
$url = 'https://www.example.in/scoreboard';

$cricket = file_get_html($url . '?nocache='. time());

$score = $cricket->find('.team-score',0)->plaintext;   // sometimes echo the previous value
```

HTML
[image]

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the original HTML please ?

Comment: What HTML has to do with it? It's more of a backend @Camille

Comment: I mean, the "https://www.example.in/scoreboard" HTML code you're parsing, so we can see what's the construction of the original dom elements.

Comment: I attached the screenshot of it! You can check it @Camille

Comment: Searching a bit the page networks, looks like the website you want to parse use an API returning a Json with results : https://ce-api-v1.appspot.com/liveMatches2.php is it the data you're looking for ?

Comment: Amazing! Is this public API? I can see that this url returns the data of homepage! Is this api available for the match pages (subpages) too? @Camille

Comment: Pretty sure that's a private API mate, you sould be careful using it. Before trying huge scraper tool, always check loading files/scripts, that's easy, with Chrome, Inspector > Network ! https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6iRi.jpg It can be a bit messy first but you sould probably find what you want for every pages.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, mate! You’re awesome! People like you make this platform worthy @Camille

Comment: Update:- This api works perfectly! But I guess I cannot use it! If I did, they most probably will block my IP

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a very busy site you're scraping. Perhaps because a lot of people are scraping it very often?

Anyway, sites that are very busy use a number of techniques to serve so many people/robots. Load-balancing between different servers, caching in various places, and many-many more.

Since the internet is basically [stateless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) your server might retrieve data from different resources and get answers that are not in chronological order. Especially if you poll very quickly.

Remember that it is not a responsibility of that website to serve you these pages in chronological order. All it needs to do is to serve them quickly and as up-to-date as possible.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a long polling technique (hit the URL after every 2 seconds to see if there is any change in the score) So Is there any solution to this problem? any recommendation?

Comment: The solution is to use a resource that is specifically designed to give up-to-date scores of the cricket. Perhaps that website you're polling has an API for this? Remember that as soon as the webmaster discovers what you're doing he might block you. This might even happen automatically. I do this on my websites, otherwise robots cause 95% of all traffic, which I have to pay for.

Comment: Understood! No, the website doesn't have any official API (that's why I was using the scraping technique), and thank you for answering my question

Comment: @anonymous: "hit the URL after every 2 seconds" - that's called "short polling", btw. Long polling is when you ask the server for updates and server waits until it give you some. And the client is waiting for a response. Possibly, for a long time. Hence the name, "long polling". Naturally, this requires active cooperation from the server.

Comment: Is it more effective compared to short polling? I guess it involves JS too? Wouldn't have I to still hit the URL to see if any change happens? @SergioTulentsev

Comment: @anonymous: the way it works, you just request the url once and it doesn't return response until there is something to respond with (new stuff). Depending on the actual implementation, it can be much more efficient or much more wasteful, compared to short-polling. As I said above, the server must support this.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Appreciate it